# Select data from another table based on field value

Tags: sql-server, select

I have three tables and I want to join data from these three in a flexible way based on value from one table's field.

This is for a self-appraisal and managerial appraisal system. I have tried solutions from other posts here, but because my data structure differs from others, none worked for me.

Tables are like this:

```
Tokens: SubmitterID, SubjectID, Origin, Token
Submitters: ID, FullName, Email
Subjects: ID, FullName, Email
```

In Tokens table:

- If Origin is 1, SubmitterID and SubjectID are the same and come from Submitters (Managerial self-appraisal).
- If Origin is 2, SubmitterID and SubjectID are the same and come from Subjects (Staff self-appraisal).
- If Origin is 3, SubmitterID comes from Submitters and SujbectID from Subjects.

I need a query to give me the following as output:

FullName of both Submitter and Subject, Email of Submitter, and Token. I have no actual output so far, because I haven't been able to write this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this cases you JOIN your table with all the possible options (both Submitters and Subjects) and then return the desired values using a conditional (CASE) depending of Origin value.

```
SELECT T.Token, 
       CASE Origin
            WHEN 1 THEN SM_Submitter.Fullname
            WHEN 2 THEN SJ_Submitter.Fullname
            WHEN 3 THEN SM_Submitter.Fullname
       END AS SubmitterFullName,
       CASE Origin
            WHEN 1 THEN SM_Subject.Fullname
            WHEN 2 THEN SJ_Subject.Fullname
            WHEN 3 THEN SJ_Subject.Fullname
       END AS SubjectFullName, 
       CASE Origin
            WHEN 1 THEN SM_Submitter.Email
            WHEN 2 THEN SJ_Submitter.Email
            WHEN 3 THEN SM_Submitter.Email
       END AS SubmitterEmail
FROM   dbo.Tokens AS T
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Submitters AS SM_Submitter ON SM_Submitter.ID = T.SubmitterID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Submitters AS SM_Subject ON SM_Subject.ID = T.SubjectID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Subjects AS SJ_Submitter ON SJ_Submitter.ID = T.SubmitterID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Subjects AS SJ_Subject ON SJ_Subject.ID = T.SubjectID
```

Comment: You are GREAT! Many many thanks! I have to look at this closely to understand how does it work exactly. P.S: It didn't work upon first copy-paste. Seems some characters are replaced before posting, possibly.

Comment: @MohammadJavahery You are welcome.Feel free to ask if you don't understand how it works.